# StringTokenizer including whitespace

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class test5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String s = "hello=i am, the king of the world";
        int sum = 0;

        StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(s, "=,;");
        while (t.hasMoreTokens()) {
            sum++;
            System.out.print(t.nextToken());
        }

        System.out.println("\n" + sum);
    }

}
```

Output:

> helloi amthe king of the world 3

No problem until about here.

If I want to include some whitespace with these tokens, how would I do that?

Changing:

```
StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(s,"=,;");
```

to this:

```
StringTokenizer t=new StringTokenizer(s," =,;");
```

gives the output:

> helloiamthekingoftheworld 8

It then overrides the other tokens.  How would I get both the whitespace and the desired tokens?

Comment: What is wrong with `helloiamthekingoftheworld 8`? You have 8 words here.

Comment: i also want to use "=" along with whitespace as the tokenizer

Comment: Why do you think that `=` is not delimiter? I dont see it in output so it had been used correctly.

Comment: damn.. it was right there in front of me...still thanks

Comment: Use `split` or ` java.util.regex` instead. `StringTokenizer` is not popular any more.

Comment: i was watching this match , saw your answer and my silliness , went to check the score , thought of deleting the ques, but by then it already had answers :(

Comment: @ zybjtu yeah..regex is in my list of topics to look into

Comment: If your question is solved, then please mark an answer as accepted.  There's no need to put "solved" in the title.

Comment: man , u even edited the grammar!!

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is alright.

You are splitting up the string "hello=i am, the king of the world" using

`StringTokenizer t=new StringTokenizer(s," =,;");`

If applied, the string is split up in eight pieces:

1. hello
2. i
3. am
4. the
5. king
6. of
7. the
8. world

...and this is exactly what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is working fine and as expected. Please use `println()` instead of `print()` to view the results correctly.

Code :

```
StringTokenizer t=new StringTokenizer(s,"=,;");
```

Output :

```
hello
i am
 the king of the world
Sum is 3
```

Code:

```
StringTokenizer t=new StringTokenizer(s," =,;");
```

Output :

```
hello
i
am
the
king
of
the
world
Sum is 8
```

Answer (score 1):

> it then over rides the other tokens apparently...how to get both the
>   whitespace and the desired tokens??

I think by this statement you mean that the other delimiters are not taken in consideration. But is it really so? No. Other tokens are also taken in to consideration.

To confirm lets look in to all the tokens printed. To make it more clear lets change the `System.out.print()` to `System.out.println()` so that all the tokens are printed into a separate line. The output is. I have included the explanation in brackets in front of each token.
The string is

> "hello=i am, the king of the world"

```
hello 
i    (split due the to delimiter =)
am    (split due to delimiter space)
the    (split due to delimiter , and space)
king   (split due to delimiter space)
of     (split due to delimiter space)
the     (split due to delimiter space)
world    (split due to delimiter space)

8
```

Hope this clears the confusion.